# Highest damage touch spells by level?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation

So I'm currently playing a Gestalt game - and have selected Barbarian and Wizard as my classes (Don't worry - me being iliterate doesn't actually stop me from casting read magic, I checked... and we are playing with a STUPID amount of points) but what I am worried about is casting spells while raging... or at least I was until I noticed an interesting reaction between delayed spells and tossing my familar, which has a stupid amount of hit points because barbarian.

So my current goal is to: Load up familiar (Weasel) with spells pre-combat, Toss them at target creature that would otherwise be a right pain in the buns to target. And when my previous touch spell ends use a standard action to activate the next spell in the pain train (Because delayed spell is activated not cast).

This all being said: My opposed schools are Illusion and Enchantment. I'ld like to know the maximum damage touch spell for each spell level that I can cast please

Comment: Are you specifically looking for touch spells that inflict the frightened condition or do you mean they'll recognize your weasel as a source of danger? Could you be more specific with what you want to accomplish with the available spells? (Overall damage output, utility for a specific use, etc) Atm the question seems to be about ideas rather than a problem for your weasel to solve.

Comment: Yeah we can't really just list off 'good' spells. That question is better suited to a forum, where there would be some back-and-forth and lists. If you give more specific criteria (negative conditions to apply, highest DPR, etc) we may be able to help

Comment: Edited appropriately sorry

Comment: Are you referring to [the Delayed Spell metamagic](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Delayed%20Spell)? It only works on spells that target squares or grid intersections, so it wouldn't allow touch spells.